# How to lanuch a post using javascript or jquery when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Code B, all checked checkbox items will be posted to server side when I click submit button, the server side will handle all checked checkbox items and recreate web page to return client side.

I hope to do the same thing in Code A, and more I hope the client side can display a Delete prompt information before post when I click the button btnDelete.

How can I write code to post all checked checkbox items to server side  using javascript or jquery ?

**Code A**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery1.10.2.min.js?isassets=1" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

     function DeleteFile() {
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete selected images?")) {  
           ...
        }        
     } 

    </script>

</head>

<body>

   <div id="container">

       <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myform">
           <input id="a1" name="subBox1" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\1.jpg"/>1.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a2" name="subBox2" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\2.jpg"/>2.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a3" name="subBox3" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\3.jpg"/>3.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a4" name="subBox4" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\4.jpg"/>4.jpg <br/> 
       </form>
       <input type="button" name="btnDelete" value="Delete Selected Images" onclick="DeleteFile()" />

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Code B**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>

   <div id="container">

       <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myform">
           <input id="a1" name="subBox1" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\1.jpg"/>1.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a2" name="subBox2" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\2.jpg"/>2.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a3" name="subBox3" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\3.jpg"/>3.jpg <br/>
           <input id="a4" name="subBox4" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\4.jpg"/>4.jpg <br/>      

           <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete Selected Images'/>
       </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the `submit` event and call the [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method when `confirm()` returns `false`.

#### JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  if (!confirm('Do you want to delete selected images?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myform">
    <input id="a1" name="subBox1" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\1.jpg"/>1.jpg <br/>
    <input id="a2" name="subBox2" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\2.jpg"/>2.jpg <br/>
    <input id="a3" name="subBox3" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\3.jpg"/>3.jpg <br/>
    <input id="a4" name="subBox4" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\4.jpg"/>4.jpg <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete Selected Images" />
   </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ndae3wm/).

Comment: And more, How can I add some additional data when I post a form ? document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  if (!confirm('Do you want to delete selected images?')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else{
     //Post some  additional data ...
  }
});